# SSIS Text file destination with a custom defined formatting

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis, msbi

I am trying to create a file with custom formatting for the destination text file. I am not sure if this can be done without creating any custom transformation.

Example:

I have a following table:

```
Date    CompanyName CompanyAddress  Phone   Amountinwords   Amount
12/16/2011  ABC Company DEF Street, Fremont, CA 12345   1234567891  Two Hundred 200
11/11/2013  XYZ Company TUV Street, Fremont, CA 12346   9087654321  Five Hundred    500
```

and expecting a result in the below format:

```
                                    12/16/2011


ABC Company
DEF Street, Fremont, CA 12345
1234567891






        Two Hundred                     

                                        200


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                                    11/11/2013


XYZ Company
TUV Street, Fremont, CA 12346
9087654321






        Five Hundred                            


                                        500


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: Yes, I am new to script task coding. so still figuring out how to code this in VB or C#. or any other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to use Script Task, and write custom script to generate required data.

The logic for script task is - read file line by line and put logic to format data as per requirement.

Follow  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324152/record-only-certain-rows-of-a-text-file-in-ssis/24324500#24324500) question, it's same like yours, only you have to reverse the process.